# Excel Sheet Referencing

Tags: excel

I made a list of sheet names contained within my doc and would like to use this list to look up information on said sheets using a formula.

For example, say my list is `Red, Blue, Yellow, Gree`n and on cell `A1` of each sheet I have a number. Is there a formula I can use to pull data from each without having to manually `type =Red!A$1, =Blue!A$1`, etc?

I had tried listing them horizontally where `Red =A1, Blue = B1, Yellow = C1` and using the `code =A1!A$1` but that doesn't parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `=A1!A$1` use the INDIRECT() Function:

```
=INDIRECT(A1&"!A1")
```

Comment: @Exion if it worked than mark it as correct, by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.  It will mark this question as being answered and clear it from the unanswered queue.